# GWT: unable to access xml

Tags: http, gwt, xml-parsing

I'm trying to access a XML file from client side in GWT. But it looks like the sendRequest method is not getting fired at all.

I'm able to see the xml in the browser. Do I need to do any thing in the server side?

Any help is appreciated.

Here's my code

```
    String xmlurl = "http://localhost:8888/test.xml";
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(xmlurl));

    try {
      Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            System.out.println(exception);
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
          if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
              System.out.println(response.getText());
          } else {
              System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
          }
        }       
      });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        System.out.println("exception"+e);  
    }
```

I tried the following code too, but have the same problem. The developer tool shows response status as 200 and correct response text. Only, its not working in the code.

```
       String xmlurl = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/test.xml";
       httpGetFile(xmlurl, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            xmlData = "Error";
        }

        public void onSuccess(String xmlText) {
            xmlData = xmlText;
        }
    });



   public static void httpGetFile(final String url, final AsyncCallback<String> callback) {
    final RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
    rb.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            try {
                System.out.println("dafadfdf");
                final int responseCode = response.getStatusCode() / 100;
                if (url.startsWith("file:/") || (responseCode == 2)) {
                    callback.onSuccess(response.getText());
                } else {
                    callback.onFailure(new IllegalStateException("HttpError#" + response.getStatusCode() + " - " + response.getStatusText()));
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                callback.onFailure(e);
            }
        }

        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            callback.onFailure(exception);
        }
    });
    try {
        rb.send();
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        callback.onFailure(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you see XML in the browser, why do you think the request is not being sent? How else would the browser get the XML other than from the server?

Comment: yeah that's what puzzles me. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I would fire up FireBug and look at the flow of requests to make sure nothing is being requested. If its being requested, is it coming back. Look on the server to make sure the correct URL is being hit and the XML is being sent. I'd also make sure there wasn't some other sort of Exception being thrown. My GWT is too old and fuzzy to offer you more.

Comment: Attach a screenshot!! You problem statement is fuzzy.

Comment: SSR - I'm trying to read a XML file in the OnModuleLoad(). Nothing in the RequestCallBack part of sendRequest method gets executed. I'm able to access the XML in the browser though.

Comment: @LeeMeador - I can see nothing wrong in developer tool. Response status is 200 but the code inside OnResponseReceived never gets executed.

Comment: The issue was because an exception. I'm able to get the XML now but the code for parsing the XML gets executed before I get the response. I'm doing all my code in OnModuleLoad(). Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you Edit your question to reflect the new information and drop one of the code snippet that is not working. "Also parsing the XML" should be done inside the "onSuccess" method of the rb callback.

Comment: @SSR - thats what i did. Its working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always Use logging instead of System.out.print statements https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging

Step 1 - Add logging statements to failure, success and try catch statements. Clean up the exception.

Step 2 - "Parsing the XML" should be done inside the "onSuccess" method of the rb callback.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a RequestBuilder at all to access an XML file. You can use an ExternalTextResource for this:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#TextResource